# Updating tasks and writting out completed tasks

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-selectors

The task I need to solve is as follows:

Every time you update a task (check it, uncheck it or add
it) the output element should be updated with the number of completed tasks and the number of tasks. E.g. if you have 7 tasks and 3 are completed, it should read '3/7 completed'.

The code above works together to solve multiple tasks before this one, but I can't seem to get the last one to work. I can't find the right variable to use to get it to write out "Tasks completed 1/2". The last number needs to change automatically with how many tasks I add, and the first number will be for each task I have checked off.

```js
//Part 3
let n = [];

function changeText() {
  let string = "";
  for (var i of n) {
    string += "<li><input type ='checkbox' onchange = 'displayCheckedGroup()'><span>" + i[0] + "</span></li>";
  }
  //const currentContent = document.querySelector('#list ul').innerHTML;
  document.querySelector('#list ul').innerHTML = string;
}

//Part 4
function addTask() {
  inputText = document.getElementById('inputText').value;
  n.unshift([inputText, Date()]);

  changeText();
  console.log(n);
}

//Part 5
function displayCheckedGroup() {
  var items = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]:checked');
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    console.log(items[i].id);
  }
  let alfa = document.querySelectorAll('#form > #row > #list > ul > input').length;

  document.getElementById('output').innerText = 'Tasks Completed: ' + i + '/' + alfa;
}
```

```html
<div id="form">
  <div id="inputForm">
    <h1>New Task</h1>
    <div id="row">
      <div id="input">
        <input type="text" id="inputText" name="addNewList">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row">
      <div id="button1">
        <button id="button" onclick="addTask()"><span>Add to list</span></button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="row">
      <div class="list1" id="list">
        <h1 id="h1">My to-do list</h1>
        <p id="output" onchange="displayCheckedGroup()"></p>
        <ul>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Part 5 is the code that should solve my problem, but I can't seem to find out why it does not work.

Comment: IDs should be unique, but you have two elements with `id="row"`. For that reason, `document.querySelectorAll('#form > #row > #list > ul > input')` will look for `#list` in the wrong place.

Comment: this should work: `document.querySelectorAll('#list > ul > input')` but your html will not be valid until you set different IDs to the aforementioned elements.

Comment: It's till won't write out the number of items in the list, so it for example says 5/0, which is very weird.

Comment: my bad, I didn't notice `input`s are not direct descendants of `ul`. Try this: `document.querySelectorAll('#list > ul input')`

Comment: It worked, but now I have another issue, if I add a new task when I already have 5 tasks in the list, it resets the whole list. The thing it should do is add a new element, update the last number in "tasks completed" and keep the completed tasks as marked. Any tips on how I can do this?

Comment: inside `Part 4`, after you call `changeText();` also call `displayCheckedGroup()`

Comment: This solved the problem about updating when adding, but it still refreshes the whole list when I tap add and have some of the elements selected. Thought it may have been a syntax error in `changeText()` , so tried to add the `displayCheckedGroup()` in the part 3, but I could not get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?